# How to get a list of stores from multi-store PrestaShop 1.7 in a custom module?

Tags: prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules, multistore

How to get a list of all stores from multishop on the product card page?

Comment: What do you want to do with that list? Back task? Render on page?

Comment: @FranCerezo I want to display a link to the page of all offers of multishop-stores with this product in the product card. Something like this: `<a href="link/to/stores-offers/page">{$multishop_stores|count}</a>`